# Slow jQuery script execution in a page hosted on Google Drive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-drive-api

I've built an authoring tool for Physics JS:

Absolutely:

https://googledrive.com/host/0B8yu2s4Q9YD8OG00WElPQllYTW8/Home.htm

The tool has been implemented with a color-swap-on-mousehover-and-mouseout
effect on image buttons.

Code:

```
$('input#b1').bind('mouseover', function() {
    $('input#b1').attr("src", "images/Begin_hover.png");
});
$('input#b1').bind('mouseout', function() {
    $('input#b1').attr("src", "images/Begin.png");
```

This works perfectly locally. But, on Google Drive it's 
taking some time.

What is the solution?

GitHub:

https://github.com/MGTHEBOSS/absolutely

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much a problem with your code, as your caching of the image (or lack thereof)-

> cache-control:**private, max-age=20**
>
> date:**Sun, 05 Jan 2014 09:34:29 GMT**
>
> expires:**Sun, 05 Jan 2014 09:34:29 GMT**
>
> last-modified:Sat, 04 Jan 2014 10:16:26 GMT
>
> location:/host/0B8yu2s4Q9YD8OG00WElPQllYTW8/images/
>
> server:GSE
>
> status:**304 Not Modified**

The max-age attribute is in seconds, and the expires value tells the browser **not** to cache it at all.

As a result a "conditional GET" is being made on each and every mouseover and mouseout by the browser to see if the image has changed. This is taking 301ms for me on a reasonable fixed line connection - the latency will be much higher on mobile networks.

Set a far-future expiration (absolute minimum an hour) to avoid this need to repeatedly fetch the image.

Which version of jQuery are you using? [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) has been the preferred method of binding events since jQuery version 1.7 - you could also make your code marginally more efficient by storing the DOM element as a variable to avoid repeated lookups.

```
var $beginButton = $('input#b1');

$beginButton.on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "images/Begin_hover.png");
});
$beginButton.on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "images/Begin.png");
```

Comment: How to set that? The page is hosted on Google Drive. And about jQuery version, the page source clearly shows that the version is 1.9.0.

Comment: Yes, but you didn't provide the version here, and I had already formulated that part of the answer as a comment before I went to visit your page. In terms of setting the expires and cache-control settings, I don't know - I have never hosted with Google Drive and host-specific setup and configuration questions are not a good fit for StackOverflow which exists to solve specific programming related issues. I did quickly Google for instructions but didn't see anything in a reasonable time, I suggest you check their documentation or contact support if you still have problems.

Comment: So, according to you, there is no code-level solution to the problem?

Comment: You could create images as variables in JavaScript (as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement.Image) and then remove the existing image from the page, replacing it with the appropriate JavaScript created image. You'd need to switch to delegate events as the object would be forever attached and destroyed, but I'm not even sure that would resolve the caching issue. The only certain way I can think of is to have two images in a parent container which you selectively show and hide. The existing code should however work fine if you can get the caching issue sorted.

Comment: I'll keep you posted.

Comment: @ManojitGhosh How did you get on with your problem? Did you manage to resolve the caching issue?